# GET API desde PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

Ya saco información desde unos equipos HaiVision mediante su API desde bash con curl, de esta forma.

```
curl -k -X POST https://192.168.30.20/api/session -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"monitor","password":"ch1ch@rr0n"}' --user "username:password"
```

Y me regresa esta información y luego la guardo en un json para ser leida desde php.

```
{
"response": {
    "type": "Session",
    "message": "Session successfully started for haiadmin",
    "sessionID": "[Session ID]",
    "lastLoginDate": 1536777877871,
    "numLoginFailures": 0
}
```

}

Lo que quiero hacer, es lo mismo desde PHP directamente, pero no encontrado forma de hacerlo.

```
    $username='monitor';
$password='ch1ch@rr0n';
$URL='https://192.168.30.20/api/session';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($cHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($cHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

Al correr el arcvhio, noe me regresa la información que se supone debe regresar y no veo error alguno en los logs del php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya tengo la solución por si a alguien mas le funciona en algún problema como el mio.

```
<?php
//
$ch = curl_init();
$headers  = [
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];
$postData = [
    'username' => 'monitor',
    'password' => 'ch1ch@rr0n'
];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://192.168.30.21/api/session");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData));           
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$result     = curl_exec ($ch);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

$obj = json_decode($result);

//PARA MOSTRAR SOLO UN VALOR DE PRUEBA
$demo = $obj->{'response'}->{'sessionID'};

echo $demo;

?>
```

FUe añadir los parametro de
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS con el que mando las credenciales
y el otro parametro fue
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER con el cual mando las cabeceras.
Retirando el parametro
CURLOPT_USERPWD puesto que este es formato usuario:contraseña y en la API me lo pide enviado en formato JSON.
Con esto ya puedo tener la información.
Saludos.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).